# Is this is the right way of storing cookie in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cookies

login form code snippet from html file

```
<form action="/phpScripts/login.php" method="post" onsubmit="getCookie()">
    User/E-mail <input id="loginname" type="text" name="uid" class="inpun"><br>

    Password <input id="loginpass" type="text" name="pass" class="inppass"><br>

            <input type="submit" name="login" value="login" ><br>
</form>
```

getCookie function code from js file

```
function getCookie()
{
   var user=document.getElementById('loginname').value;
   var expires=new Date();
   expires.setFullYear(expires.getFullYear()+1);
   document.cookie=encodeURIComponent("name")+ "="+encodeURIComponent(user)+ "; expires=" + expires.toTimeString()+ "; domain=.xyz.com";
   alert(document.cookie);
}
```

login.php (form action) do the database query stuff and checks for authentication and if all is well it stores session variables(username in the login form) and redirect to the home page. I want to store username in javascript cookies also so that i can load user specific data like users profile pic from the folders created in the root document directory at the time of registering (signup) for example:-

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var usr=document.cookie;

/*location=url(data/abc/abc.jpg)*/

location="url(data/" + usr + "/" + usr +".jpg" + ")";

$(div#profilepic).css({'background-image':location, 'width':'180px', 'height': '180px'});

});
```

please correct me if I am wrong in the jquery code above. Also is there any way to store php $_SESSION data in javascript variable?

Comment: *Note: there is a plugin that might help you, [jQuery.cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie)*

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp you can create cookie in PHP by passing JS cookie in ajax.

Comment: @Bigood nothing is working. Is using `onsubmit` and `<form action="">` simultaneously creating problem in storing cookie. I mean is there a conflict in which operation is to be performed first either calling function on submit or loading the page given in action attribute

Comment: @UDB Just to add, worth checking out this very good article on cookies:
http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html#script